# React does not update style on rerender

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I have a React component, which visibility and position can be changed by the user.

The visibility by adding and removing a CSS class, the position by a function, which sets the new position after Drag & Drop as top and left.

That works, but my problem is that React does not update the style (and therefore does not rewrite the position to initial), when the component gets rerendered for the visiblity.

```
class MoveableCard extends React.Component {
    ...
    render() {
        ...
        return <div className={(this.props.isVisible ? '' : 'hide')}
                    draggable="true" onDragStart={dragStart}
                    style={{top:'initial', left:'initial'}}>
            ...
        </div>
    }
}



function dragStart(event) {
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(event.target, null)
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", JSON.stringify({
        id:event.target.getAttribute('data-reactid'),
        x:(parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left"),10) - event.clientX),
        y:(parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top"),10) - event.clientY)
    }))
}
function dragOver(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    return false
} 
function drop(event) {
    let data = JSON.parse(event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"))
    let el = document.querySelectorAll("[data-reactid='" + data.id + "']")[0]

    el.style.left = (event.clientX + parseInt(data.x, 10)) + 'px'
    el.style.top = (event.clientY + parseInt(data.y, 10)) + 'px'

    event.preventDefault()
    return false
}
document.body.addEventListener('dragover',dragOver,false)
document.body.addEventListener('drop',drop,false)
```

When the Card is rendered for the first time, the style looks like `style="top: initial; left: initial;"`.

When the Card gets moved, the style looks like `style="top: 162px; left: 320px;"`.

When the Card is closed, the class `hide` gets added, but the style remains `style="top: 162px; left: 320px;"`, no matter, how I create the style object.

So, how can I force React to update the style?
Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of React. Instead of manipulating the dom element's style you should be using React's `state` and calling `this.setState` which will automatically call `render` for you https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Just as the comment above, you should use the react API library to control your elements/components so that it can re-render on state/prop changes. Using the DOM directly is the opposite of what react is doing behind the scenes because react creates a virtual DOM whereas you are adding an event listener on the regular DOM. Any event registered to a DOM element works but it will not be re-rendered by react because react operates on a separate DOM (the virtual DOM)

Comment: But how can I access my React object only by the dom element? The Drop Function, which contains my position, is called on the element, where I drop my element, not on the moving one.

Comment: You can add a ref to it: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html or pass a callback using a parent component as a property. https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17

Answer (score 1):

**Short version of the answer:**

Use inner state and the component lifecycle

**Long version:**

First of all, I would recommend putting your event handlers inside the component instead of global methods:

```
class MoveableCard extends React.Component {
  dragStart(event) {}
  dragOver(event) {}
  drop(event) {}
}
```

Secondly, in the constructor of the component, bind the this-context of the component to those handlers. (Well that, or you use arrow functions inside the render method)

```
constructor() {
  this.dragStart = this.dragStart.bind(this);
  this.dragOver = this.dragOver.bind(this);
  this.drop = this.drop.bind(this);
}
```

In order to let the component 'update' or re-render, I would recommend mutating its inner state in this case. Therefore, you first add an initial value in the initial state within componentWillMount.

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.state = { top: 0, left: 0 };
}
```

Within the event handlers, you can now update top and left on the innerState, using this.setState (and that's what you needed to bind this for).

```
drop() {
   // Assuming you filled in this.left and this.top in the dragOver method
   this.setState({ top: this.top, left: this.left });
}
```

By using the setState, a re-render will be triggered with the new values on the inner state. Now, you can use `this.state.top` and `this.state.left` in your render method:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className={(this.props.isVisible ? '' : 'hide')}
         draggable="true"
         onDragStart={this.dragStart}
         style={{top: this.state.top, left: this.state.left}}>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got a solution based on Andrew, dejakob and Chris answers, so thank you all :)

I thought initially, I could not move the Functions into the Component, because the Drop Event with the final position was emitted by the element, where I drop my Card, not by the Card itself.

But there is a `dragend` Event, which is emitted by the Card and contains the position.

Now I only had to use this to set the position in the state (and remove it via a ref to `unsetPosition` in the parent).

```
class MoveableCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            styles: {top:'initial', left:'initial'}
        }
        this.drop = this.drop.bind(this);
    }

    dragStart(e) {
        let style = window.getComputedStyle(e.target, null)

        this.setState({l: parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left")) - e.clientX, y: parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top")) - e.clientY})
    }

    drop(e) {
        this.setState({left: this.state.l + e.clientX, top: this.state.y + e.clientY})

        e.preventDefault()
        return false
    }

    unsetPosition() {
       this.setState({styles: {top:'initial', left:'initial'}})
    }

    render() {
        return <div className={(this.props.isVisible ? '' : 'hide')}
                    draggable="true"
                    onDragStart={this.dragStart}
                    onDragEnd={this.drop}
                    style={this.state.styles}>
            ...
        </div>
    }
}
```